# Can you change the Excel Autorecovery location for just specific workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, security, microsoft-office, file-recovery, microsoft-excel-365

I have some Excel files on my computer's hard drive that are not particularly important, so the default Autorecovery path `%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel` (on C: drive) is just fine. I have *other* Excel files for work which contain sensitive information and are saved on an encrypted external HDD, which I unmount when not actively using.

These external-drive Excel workbooks still save their Autorecovery .XLSB files to the default path on the unencrypted C: drive, which obviously presents a huge security risk. I don't want to disable Autorecovery completely for my work files, because it *is* a handy feature that has saved me from data loss in the past.

Is there any way to change the Autorecovery path for just certain Excel workbooks, so I can set my external-drive workbooks to save their Autorecovery files on the same external drive? I don't see any options to do this inside Excel, and the only other workarounds I can think of involve using two different side-by-side installations of Excel to handle personal vs. work files, or switching to some different more-fully-featured spreadsheet program completely, neither of which are preferable). If I password-protect the work excel file itself (not preferable, but doable), would the .XLSB file also be password-protected?

Comment: Theoretically you could put code in the workbook_start event that sets the auto recover location, but then any workbook open will use that and it will always be what was opened last.

Comment: What about just turning Autorecovery off for these workbooks?  Test to see if this turns Autorecovery off for all workbooks

Comment: @John - “I don't want to disable Autorecovery completely for my work files, because it is a handy feature that has saved me from data loss in the past.”

Comment: Of course.  I wanted to see if you could test a method for just one workbook.

Comment: @John, yes you can turn off autorecovery on a per-workbook basis. But as mentioned, ideally I would like to keep it enabled for all workbooks.

Comment: The reason I suggested autorecovery off per workbook, is that if on for all books, then the autorecovery location will be the same for all workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

The AutoSave path is set for all Excel spreadsheets in the computer,
and is not specific to just one spreadsheet.

The only way I can think of this working is if you isolate these
spreadsheets in their own environment that is isolated from the
rest of the computer.

This could for example be done using
[Sandboxie Plus](https://sandboxie-plus.com/):

> It creates a sandbox-like isolated operating environment in which applications can be run or installed without permanently modifying the local or mapped drive. An isolated virtual environment allows controlled testing of untrusted programs and web surfing.

This would need a careful setup, where some folders are exempt from
the sandbox and common to the host system. You would also need to
always open these spreadsheets inside the sandbox, or you will have
a mess-up.

I'm not sure that this solution is worth the trouble and the
constraints that it will put on your work, but I can't think of
another one.

Comment: Yeah, if I were going to install something anyway, it would probably be the "using two different side-by-side installations of Excel" I mentioned. Aka installing Office 2019 alongside 365, since I'm fairly certain it lets you do that.

Comment: Yes, each installation has its own registry keys. However, as far as I know Office 2019 and 365 are both version 16, so share a single registry key at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0`. So this particular combination of versions might not be separate.

Comment: Good to know! The mention of reg keys raises an interesting idea, though. The autorecovery save path is stored in a key, so I could make 2 macros for my work workbooks: 1) On workbook open, change autorecovery path to the removable drive, 2) After save and before exit, revert path to previous. As long as I'm not trying to edit work and personal workbooks simultaneously (simple enough to remember) there shouldn't be any issues. And if Excel crashes without saving.. Well I can fix the path manually after recovering my unsaved data

Comment: This has to be tested. I have not suggested it, because if you once forget to undo that you will have a mess. But coming to think of, if you always start Office via a batch file that first sets the registry and then starts the Office app then this might work. But beware of double-clicking an Office file. But this needs testing.